# PHP error reporting and mail()

Tags: php, error-handling, sendmail, error-reporting

I've currently got `set_error_handler()` throwing `ErrorException` whenever anything is encountered. Furthermore, I've got `error_reporting()` at `-1`, so mis-indexing an array throws an exception.

Anyways, that being a cursory overview of my error/reporting environment; the PHP `mail()` function is tossing errors on my (*Win7*) dev machine, during a process intended for a project, 'cause I don't have a mail server installed. I tried prefixing it with `@` to shut it up, but it still triggers an error, and hence throws an exception. I could wrap it with `try{}`, but I'm curious as to why it won't shut up.

Why won't it shut up?

**To reiterate, we can almost remove `mail()` from the equation (*so far as I can tell*); I just want to know why `@` wouldn't do it's job under such a circumstance, with `mail()` or any function. I just figured `mail()` may be special case for some reason.**

---

Thanks to our friend `XDebug`:

> ( ! ) ErrorException: mail() [function.mail]: Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\xampp\htdocs\dbc_relaunch_2-0-0\mf\handlers\api\mail\send.php on line 16

---

Alrighty, I've simply gone with:

```
try{
    mail($args);
catch(Exception $exception){
    return $failure;
}
return $success;
```

Rather than:

```
if(@mail($args)){
    return $failure;
}
return $success;
```

And all is well; I'm browsing the answer @Pheonix linked, but anyone with a short order response as to why this is free to answer.

Comment: What kind of errors? What are they about?

Comment: What is the error?  I suspect `@mail()` isn't the actual source.

Comment: Sorry, should have included, one sec.

Comment: @Pheonix - The link there to PHP is dead, I'm searching the archive but comments suggest "*black magic*" is afoot, and I'd sooner just `try{}` it, however the lack of `@` success is perplexing me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you show us your error handler? Note that your handler will be called in case of an error, regardless of your `error_reporting()` setting and even if you prepend your function with an `@`.

> Of particular note is that this value
>   will be 0 if the statement that caused
>   the error was prepended by the @
>   error-control operator.

From the manual page of [`set_error_handler()`](http://php.net/set_error_handler).

If you don't want to throw exceptions for errors caused by an `@` prefixed expression, you'll have to check the return value of `error_reporting()` in your handler. In case it returns zero, you're dealing with a suppressed error.

Comment: Spot on sir. All my error handler does is throw an `ErrorException`; I needed to filter the silenced errors.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an Interesting read

[How do I catch a PHP Fatal Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277224/how-do-i-catch-a-php-fatal-error)

This page discusses exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a very good answer, but I suspect it's because error 'messages' and error 'exceptions are not the same.

[php-exceptions-vs-errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/841500/php-exceptions-vs-errors) says a little about this, but what I found was that, as per [this comment](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php#98895), it appears that `set_error_handler()` actually overrides the @ symbol.

That said, try, catch is always the best approach when dealing with exceptions.

Hope that helped a little.