# try catch exception?

Tags: php

I have some script, that calls an error: `Fatal error: Call to a member function GetData() on a non-object in ...`. I'm trying to catch this error, but it doesn't work, watch my code below:

```
try {

    if ($data = $m->users()->GetData()) {

    print_r( $data );

}

}
catch (Exception $e) {

    echo 'Hey, it is an error man!';

}
```

How to catch it? Turning off all errors in php is impossible. I mean that sometimes I really need this error.

**upd** 1. Well, solution is simple:

```
if (is_object($m->users()) && ($data = $m->users()->GetData())) {
    print_r( $data );
} else {
echo 'Hey, it is an error man!';
```

Thank you all!

Comment: first of all, echo 'Hey, it's an error man!'; should be echo "Hey, it's an error man!";

Comment: sorry, I was typing it, not copy-past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP errors and exceptions are from different separated worlds. Look more 
[PHP: exceptions vs errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/841500/php-exceptions-vs-errors)

You can check returned object before call method `GetData()`

```
try {
    if (is_object($m->users()) && ($data = $m->users()->GetData())) {
        print_r( $data );
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Hey, it's an error man!';
}
```

Comment: really, it's my fault, damn, can I avoid this message anyhow, except usage configuration of php? I'm trying if/else, but it's ... the same t-r-o-u-b-l-e.

Comment: yes, it was helpful, but strange a one moment still, if it's not an object it's echoes nothing (would be glad if it does).

Answer (score 1):

use following to avoid your error and you should used shutdown error handler.

```
try {

    $obj =  $m->users();
    if ($data =$obj->GetData()) {

    print_r( $data );

}

}
catch (Exception $e) {

    echo 'Hey, it's an error man!';

}
```

//shut down error handler

```
function shutdownErrorHandler() {
    $error = error_get_last();
    if ($error !== NULL) {
      echo "Error: [SHUTDOWN] error type: " . $error['type'] . " | error file: " . $error['file'] . " | line: " . $error['line'] . " | error message: " . $error['message'] . PHP_EOL;
    } else {
       echo "Normal shutdown or user aborted";
    }
}

register_shutdown_function('shutdownErrorHandler');
```

Answer (score 0):

Fatal Errors are not the same as Exceptions, and they are not usually recoverable. What they are, however, is usually avoidable, and sometimes they are "catchable" via PHP5's [set_error_handler](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) function.

Best practice, however, is to simply do the work of checking for valid objects before trying to call methods on them.