# Why try-catch isn't working with phpseclib library in Laravel 5.5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5, phpseclib

I am working on one project that requires me to execute some commands on remote server. I am using Laravel 5.5 with package name "laravelcollective/remote" that uses SSH2 to connect with the remote server.

However, I am facing some really weird issues with some servers. I get the following error message on some of the servers.

> production.ERROR: Connection closed prematurely {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Connection closed prematurely at /home/username/application_name/public_html/vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php:3821, RuntimeException(code: 0): Unable to connect to remote server. at /home/username/application_name/public_html/vendor/laravelcollective/remote/src/Connection.php:143)

I am using `try-catch` block to catch exceptions but I am unable to catch this exception. All other Exceptions like `connection timed out` are being caught by the try-catch block except this one.

I am using try catch block like this:

```
try {
    $commands = array('sudo apt-get update','sudo apt-get upgrade -y');
    SSH::run($commands);
} catch (\Exception $e){
    report($e);
}
```

But the try-catch block stops working with this `connection closed prematurely` error. I don't know if I am missing something or there is some bug with the library, has anyone faced the same issue before? How can I catch this error the right way?

Answer (score 0):

it's because an exception is not thrown, just an error. and an error cannot be caught.

I suggest you set a global error handler that converts all the errors to exceptions, as seen in [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/842882/3366437) and it would be a good idea to read other answers to that question too.

Generate a custom exception handler and then in a provider or in your public/index.php set your error handler