# How to hide PHP error when using try catch

Tags: php, try-catch, phpexcel

I am doubt of PHP's try catch mechanism about why when l using try catch to process the error, but PHP still show the default error message

For example, l'm using PHP excel lib to parse the `xls` file, but l wanna to print a user friendly error output, like

```
{code:1, msg:"some error"}
```

So l do these:

```
    try {
        return $this->getJSON($fileName);
    }catch (Exception $e){
        $f = fopen('/' . trim(ROOT_DIR, '/\\') . '/file/Excel_error', 'wb');
        fwrite($f, $e);
        $split_content = "\n\n-------------------------------------\n\n";
        fwrite($f, $split_content);
        fclose($f);
        echo json_encode(array(
            "code" => 10000,
            "msg" => "Excel parse error",
            "files"=>null
        ));
    }
```

l want to log the error file and output my custom msg to front-end, but it doesn't work, When l trigger a error/warning or others, PHP still show the `PHP Error`/`E_WARINING` ... like follow screenshot

[image]

PS: l process the file in `getJSON()`, this function is my entrance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: exceptions vs errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/841500/php-exceptions-vs-errors)

Answer (score 1):

You can change the error handling and logging section in the `php.ini` file. You could change the value of the `error_reporting` to E_ERROR to reduce the verbosity of the reporting and to avoid the warnings to be displayed.