# PHP Group all exceptions into just one

Tags: php, exception

**I have a file with all my custom exceptions:**

```
class InvalidEmailException extends Exception {
    public function errorMessage() {
        return 'Please enter a valid email address';
    }
}

class ExistingEmailException extends Exception {
    public function errorMessage() {
        return 'An account with this email address already exists';
    }
}

// More...
```

**And every time I want to show the error of one I must use:**

```
try {
    // Code with several possible exceptions...
} catch (\InvalidEmailException $th) {
    $responser->showError($th->errorMessage());
} catch (\ExistingEmailException $th) {
    $responser->showError($th->errorMessage());
} // More...
```

What I want is to create an interface or something similar that allows me to **call the** `errorMessage()` **method of the required exception without indicating each and every one of them separately**. Something like this:

```
catch (\ExceptionManager $th) { // All-in-One
    $responser->showError($th->errorMessage());
}
```

I do not know if I have explained myself and not if it is possible, but I have tried it with an interface and obviously PHP asks me to add all methods of the Exception class to each one. Thanks!

Comment: just `\Exception` would catch-all

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
try {
    // Code with several possible exceptions...
} catch (\Exception $ex) {
    $responser->showError($ex->getMessage());
}
```

Or if you are using PHP 7 or greater:

```
try {
    // Code with several possible exceptions...
} catch (\Trowable $th) {
    $responser->showError($th->getMessage());
}
```

Notice, the `$th->getMessage()` method instead of `$th->errorMessage()`
Also, let's be aware that exception and error in PHP are two [different things](https://stackoverflow.com/q/841500/14066311).

- `\Exception` will catch exceptions.
- `\Error` will catch error exceptions
- `Throwable` will catch both.

You can support PHP 5 and 7 by combining the two:

```
try {
    // Code with several possible exceptions...
} catch (\Exception $ex) {
    $responser->showError($ex->getMessage());
} catch (\Trowable $th) {
    $responser->showError($th->getMessage());
}
```

- [Exception handling](https://netgen.io/blog/modern-error-handling-in-php)
- [Throwable exceptions and errors](https://trowski.com/2015/06/24/throwable-exceptions-and-errors-in-php7/)