# Errors in PHP 7 - why set_error_handler() can't catch this type of error?

Tags: php, exception, types, error-handling, php-7

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError...

Why is this **an exception** according to PHP if TypeError inherits from Error? Why can't `set_error_handler()` catch this type of error?

https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.typeerror.php

```
function myFunction(int $parameter)
{
    return $parameter;
}
function handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
{
    echo 'handler';
}
set_error_handler("handler");
myFunction('george');
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.error.php. `Error` implements [Throwable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.throwable.php)

Comment: Error implements Throwable, as does Exception. But it's unclear why you think PHP thinks it's an exception

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/841500/php-exceptions-vs-errors may be useful to read (all the answers, not just the accepted one)

Comment: hi @ADyson, my question is why set_error_handler() can't catch this type of error.

Comment: You'd better [edit] your post to actually ask that, then. And show some code which fails to catch it :-)

Comment: Try adding an [exception handler](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php) as well and see if that catches it (since both implements the Throwable interface, while a "old-school" error follows a different pattern)

Comment: hello @M. Eriksson, an exception handler with `Throwable` or `Exception` type declaration does solve it, but I don't understand why?

Comment: PHP suffers from a lot of inconsistent legacy baggage which makes these things a bit confusing and inconsistent. Many errors have been changed into throwables, but not all. A common pattern is to set an error hander that basically just throws the errors as [ErrorExceptions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.errorexception.php) and then set an exception handler that actually deals with it (showing a nice error page etc).

Comment: ...and to add to it, you can also set up a [shutdown function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php) that can deal with syntax/parse errors (since those won't go through the error or exception handlers)

Comment: This is a really good walk through of PHP's error/exception handling: https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting

Comment: excellent @M. Eriksson, I had heard that this in PHP was a DISASTER, but wanted to confirm. I loved the ErrorException pattern you recommended, I will apply it. +5.