# PHP is not catching the errors

Tags: php

I can't catch the error with the `Exception` PHP class.

```
<?php
require "vendor/autoload.php";

use App\Events\Logger;
use Exception;
/* Alterntly id tryed to use this call but dosnt work either use \Exception as Exception; */

$logger = new Logger("error.log", "ERROR");

try {
    new DosentExist(); //I force the exception.
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "error";
    $error = new Error($e->getCode(), $e->getMessage(), $e->getFile(), $e->getLine());
    $logger->log((string) $error, "ERROR");
}
```

Console error:

```
$ php index.php
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "DosentExist" not found in C:\code\php\logs-forfun\index.php:10
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in C:\code\php\logs-forfun\index.php on line 10
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the error message, you'll see that it does not mention `Exception`, but rather mentions an "Uncaught Error". You'd need to catch an `Error`, not an `Exception`:

```php
try {
    new DosentExist(); //I force the exception.
} catch (Error $e) {
    echo "error";
}
```

Comment: How can I force an exception and not an error?

Comment: See [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/842882/19655631) that describes a way to convert `Error`s into `Exception`s.