# Is there a technical reason not to use try catch for retrieving properties that may not be set

Tags: php

Is there a big performance penalty for throwing an error instead of checking if a variable is set.

For example.
With a try catch

```
public function getProperty(): int
{
    try {
        return $this->getDetail('some-detail');
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Or with isset

```
public function getProperty(): int
{    
    return isset($this->getDetail('some-detail')) ? $this->getDetail('some-detail') ? 0;
    // or even $this->getDetail('some-detail') ?? 0; in php7
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Neither of the options will actually work in the intended way (which I assume is to send a default value in case the value is not set correctly).

The following code will still throw an error if `$this->getDetail` does not return an integer

```php
public function getProperty(): int
{    
    return $this->getDetail('some-detail') ??  0; // PHP prior to 7 did not support return type hints 
}
```

The following code will catch any exceptions thrown by `getDetail` but will still fail if the result is not an integer because of the `: int` part.

```
public function getProperty(): int
{
    try {
        return $this->getDetail('some-detail');
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The ways that would actually work and could be debated are :

Catch the correct error you're expecting

```
public function getProperty(): int
{
    try {
        return $this->getDetail('some-detail');
    } catch (TypeError $e) {
        return 0;
    } 
}
```

Check if the correct return type is about to be returned:

```
public function getProperty(): int
{
    $value = $this->getDetail('some-detail');
    return is_int($value) ? $value : 0;
}
```

Just to note, that the exception handling is indeed slower to run when triggered but code which does not trigger exceptions (which should be most of it) runs as fast whether it's within or outside a try catch block. ([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104329/performance-of-try-catch-in-php) and [Source](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/339b9d070efe104fa359edd5e503dd7a518730ac))

Personally I think this is exactly the situation where exception handling should be used: It's caused by exceptional circumstances, it's rare (I hope), and we have a way to recover from it without bringing the entire request to a halt.

Answer (score -1):

It makes sense to throw exceptions, instead of checking the existence of a variable, if the logic of the program is designed to ensure that this variable must exist and further execution of the program is impossible without it. Or, higher than the level of the call stack, an exception must be returned so that the event handles correctly. For example, if we want to inform the user about a problem. In any case, this is a matter of architecture.

Comment: Yes, if the exceptions was going to be use, that would make sense to me too, but in this case is not. In this case is use to return a default value.